# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta de dos tablas foráneas en Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Proveedores(models.Model):
    idproveedor=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    direccion=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefono =models.IntegerField()
    email= models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Compras(modesl.Model):
    idcompra=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idproveedor= models.ForeignKey(proveedores,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    producto= models.ChartField(max_length=30)
    costo= models.FloatField()
    fecha = models.DateField()
```

Lo más aproximado que pude hacer fue implementarlo `sql`,  como se muestra en la imagen:

```
In [7]: from django.db import connection
In [8]: datos = connection.cursor()
In [9]: datos.execute("select entronque1_proveedores.nombre, entronque1_compras.* from entronque1_proveedores, entronque1_proveedores.idproveedor = entronque1_compras.idproveedor_id")
Out[9]: 3
In [10]: datosOpt = datos.fetchall()
In [11]: datos
Out[11]: <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper at 0xb502846c>
In [12]: datosOpt
Out[12]:  
(('pesi', 1, 'pepsi-cola', 34.0, datetime.date(2016, 2, 12), 5),  
('coca', 7, 'fanta', 7.0, datetime.date(2016, 1, 11), 3),  
('pesi', 8, 'mirinida', 5.0, datetime.date(2016, 1, 19), 5))
```

Si bien obtengo los datos no los puedo manejar fácilmente como sería en una consulta echa con `Tabla.objects.filter()`.

¿Alguna manera de mejorar mi consulta para poder acceder a los datos mas fácil? Ejemplo `tabla.id` o `tabla`.

Comment: Estaría excelente que pudieras agregar tu código con markdown, con las imagenes es difícil enterderlo.

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imágenes con código. En vez de eso incluye el código directamente en la pregunta, de esa forma es más fácil de leer y quien quiera usarlo para hacer alguna prueba tiene la posibilidad de copiarlo.

Comment: qué valores esperas obtener exactamente de la consulta?

Comment: gracias por sus sugerencias chicos.

Comment: en cuanto a tu pregunta @mascoquera deseo otener: de proveedores el nombre y de compras todos los atributos como los datos que se muestran en mi consulta sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes acceso a un `proveedor`, puedes usar la [relación inversa](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
>>> from app.models import Proveedores
>>> proveedor = Provedoores.objects.get(nombre='pesi')
>>> for compra in proveedor.compras_set.all():
...     print (proveedor.nombre, compra.producto, compra.costo, compra.fecha)
('pepsi', 'pepsi-cola', 34.0, datetime.date(2016, 2, 12))
('pepsi', 'mirinida', 5.0, datetime.date(2016, 1, 19))
```

Pero me parece que lo mas sencillo es que simplemente iteres `Compras` y lo ordenes por el proveedor:

```
>>> from app.models import Compras
>>> for compra in Compras.objects.all().order_by('idproveedor'):
...     print (compra.idproveedor.nombre, compra.producto, compra.costo, compra.fecha)
('coca', 'fanta', 7.0, datetime.date(2016, 1, 11))
('pepsi', 'pepsi-cola', 34.0, datetime.date(2016, 2, 12))  
('pepsi', 'mirinida', 5.0, datetime.date(2016, 1, 19))
```

### Bonus:

El último ejemplo lo podrías usar en una vista:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Compras

def mis_compras(request):
    compras = Compras.objects.all().order_by('idproveedor'):
    return render(request, 'mis_compras.html', {'compras': compras})
```

Y en un `<table></table>` de `mis_compras.html`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Proveedor</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Costo</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for compra in compras %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ compra.idproveedor.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ compra.producto }}</td>
                <td>{{ compra.costo }}</td>
                <td>{{ compra.fecha }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% end %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Recomendaciones:

- Los nombres de las clases en tu modelo deberían comenzar con mayúscula:

  ```
  class Tabla(models.Model): # Si

  class tabla(models.Model): # No
  ```
- Los nombres de los modelos deberían ser en singular (por ejemplo, cuando usas el siguiente modelo, instancias **una persona**, no varias):

  ```
  class Persona(models.Model): # Si

  class Personas(models.Model): # No
  ```
- A menos que sea necesario, no necesitas crear tu propio Foreign Key en los modelos:

  ```
  class Compra(modesl.Model): 
      idcompra=models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # No es necesario


  class Compra(models.Model):
      # Por defecto, Django crea el FK: compra.id
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias voy a implementar tu sugerencia

Comment: Gracias por ayuda
su sugerencia ya se implemento y resolvió mi problema bastante bien.           
**Recomiendo totalmente a la comunidad**

Comment: @harriroot que bueno! De nada ;)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma de hacer una consulta con el orm de Django sin que crezcan el numero de queries, es utilizar **select_related()** para hacer un inner join entre los dos modelos a traves de FK.

Ejemplo:

```
proveeedores = Proveedores.object.all()
provedor = proveedores[0]
Compras.objects.select_related().filter(idproveedores=proveedor.id)
```

De todos modos creo que el modelo no hace falta ponerle idproveedores porque Django mapea objeto con objeto; quiero decir que el modelo podria quedar asi:

```
class Compras(modesl.Model):
    proveedor= models.ForeignKey(Proveedores)
    producto= models.ChartField(max_length=30)
    costo= models.FloatField()
    fecha = models.DateField()
```

Django genera automaticamente los ids, estan, pero no hace falta definirlos. Del mismo modo para joinear tablas no hace falta especificar el id y pasandole el objeto completo se filtra correctamente:

```
proveeedores = Proveedores.object.all()
provedor = proveedores[0]
Compras.objects.select_related().filter(proveedor=proveedor)
```